# Update en SQL con visual studio que valide si el numero ya existe no actualice

Tags: c#, sql, studio, visual

Tengo que asignar un numero de gafete ya impreso en una tabla de usarios, pero al querer hacer el update en la columna quiero que primero verifique si el numero no esta asignado ya para no generar duplicidad de gafetes

mi codigo del update es este

```
public bool Actualizara(string idofi, string Acreditacion )
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string asString = now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");



            conexion.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("update usuarios set [# Credencial] = '{0}', [Hr credencial] = '{2}' where [ID Oficial] = {1}", new string[] { Acreditacion, idofi, asString }), conexion);
            int filasafectadas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conexion.Close();
            if (filasafectadas > 0) return true;
            else return false;
        }
```

Comment: Si suponemos que cada empleado tiene un número de empleado **ÚNICO**, por qué no mejor asignas ese número al gafete?

Comment: qué has intentado? por qué no usas el id como primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bienvenido compañero,

Lo único que se me ocurre, es hacer una subconsulta en el where, de este modo:

```
public bool Actualizara(string idofi, string Acreditacion )
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    string asString = now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");

    conexion.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("update usuarios set [# Credencial] = '{0}', [Hr credencial] = '{2}' where [ID Oficial] = {1} and not exist(select 1 from usuarios [# Credencial] == '{0}')", new string[] { Acreditacion, idofi, asString }), conexion);
    int filasafectadas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conexion.Close();
    if (filasafectadas > 0) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

He deducido que usas SQL Server, porque no indicas ninguna base de datos (MySQL, PostgreSQL, MongoBD, MariaBD, SQL Server, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizar una validacion previa antes de actualizar

```
public bool ExisteCredencial(string credencial)  
{  

    string sql = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE [# Credencial] = @credencial";   
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string"))   
    {   
        conn.Open();  

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);   
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@credencial", credencial);   

        int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());   

        return count > 0;   
    }   
}
```

Entonces lo usas antes de la actualizacion

```
public bool Actualizara(int idofi, string Acreditacion)
{
    if(ExisteCredencial(Acreditacion))
    {
        //la credencial existe
        return false;
    }

    conexion.Open();

    string update = "update usuarios set [# Credencial] = @credencial, [Hr credencial] = @fecha where [ID Oficial] = @Id";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(update, conexion);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@credencial", Acreditacion);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", DateTime.Now);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", idofi);

    int filasafectadas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conexion.Close();

    return filasafectadas > 0;

}
```

como veras usa siempre parametros, no se concatena los valore en el string

Comment: Es una buena solución, @Leandro Tuttini, aunque yo creo que la de Rubén es más óptima por aquello de que se ahorra una conexión de BBDD.

Comment: Depende como programes, si estas pensando en una capa de datos separando logica de negocio con validaciones y necesitas informar al usuario que esa credencial ya existe, entonces se debe separar, pero bueno es mi sugerencia puede no tomarla. Lo que si remarco el uso de parametros, concatenar en el string no es bueno

Comment: Correcto. En la parte de parametrización estoy de acuerdo contigo, Leandro :) Respecto al método, bueno, supongo que ambos métodos serían de la capa de datos, y que si solo vas a construir el método de checking de credencial para ese consumo mi opinión era que se podía ahorrar. Pero como tú bien indicas, son opiniones :)